# ScrollView is stealing touching events

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I have inherited UIImageview and override methods **touchesBegan,touchesMoved,touchesEnded**
and I am drawing line by finger and it works on iPhone(no scroll on side). Problem is when I start on iPad there is always scroll on side by default and I think scroll is stealing touching events. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[yourScrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO]
```